# need help in C# and SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I am creating an application in C# with SQL server as backend. I need to capture sql server error and show it on C# GUI. For example : (In SQL server) I create a table having columns ID, Name,Age etc where ID being Primary key and if i insert same values in ID twice SQL server gives error. I want this kind of error to be displayed on C# GUI so that when a user enters duplicate data through C# form into SQL server then and there itself an error be generated. I need the code of this please...
Thanks

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: The problem, is that OP want the code ;)

Comment: At a high level (since there's no code to go on in the question and it's a very broad question), what you want to do is catch exceptions from your data access code and handle those exceptions by displaying a friendly error in the UI.  More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx

Comment: This question is too generic and shows no effort. I'd recommend you to search for some examples or tutorials, and, in a broader experience to read some book on the subject

Answer (score 2):

typically the error is thrown by the .net classes...you really need to provide more code or context to your question

```
try
{
   // ...
   SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery( ... );
}
catch( Exception ex )
{
   MessageBox.Show( ex.ToString( ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try
{
    //Run query here
}
catch(SqlException e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture the exception you can use *try* and *catch*:

```
try
{
//Your command here
}
catch (Exception e)
{
//Now you can use e.Message OR e.ToString() to get the message.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to extend Timmerz's answer since you could see a whole stack trace if you display the exception itself.  If you wan something short and precise for the user to see then do the following:

```
try
{
   // ...
   SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery( ... );
}
catch( SqlException SqlEx )
{
  string errMsg = String.Empty;

  switch(SqlEx.number)
  {
     case 100:
       errMsg = "blah blah blah";
       break;
     case 200:
       errMsg = "blah blah blah";
       break;
     case 300:
       errMsg = "blah blah blah";
       break;

  }

  if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(errMsg))
  {
     //If you want a pop up display message
     MessageBox.Show( errMsg );


     //If you want to display it on a label of a form
     Form1.Labelx.text = errMsg;
  }


}
```

For the SqlEx.number value, you can either create an enum to check for it or you can refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645603.aspx for all the possible number returned from the SQL server exception.

Hope this helps